# How to use Express.js with Nuxt 3

Tags: node.js, express, server, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

how can i connect Express.js with Nuxt 3? I cant find any tutorials... i want it in the `/server` directory. How can i achieve this?

Example of server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Middleware to parse JSON requests
app.use(express.json());

// Define API route
app.get('/api/auth', (req, res) => {
  return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Authentication successful' });
});

// Start Express server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

This code doesn't work.. how do i connect it so when i go to `/api/auth` i get the message?

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/a/77442574/11107541

Comment: check this: https://dev.to/mihaiandrei97/nuxt3-express-api-bf5

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure but I think you won't be able to use express with Nuxt 3 that way inside the `server` dir. Nuxt3 uses [nitro as a server](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server). It handles the routing stuff.

One possible way to use the express app with Nuxt 3 is a headless approach like other frameworks laravel/django. Create your backend using express & use Nuxt 3 as the front-end. Basically, create REST API in the express back-end app & use that API in Nuxt font-end.

1. For protecting the auth routes you can use Nuxt middleware.
2. For fetching data you can use Nuxt useFetch composables.
3. For creating the interceptors (CSRF/access token/refresh tokens) you can use Nuxt custom-defined composables.

Have a [look at this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NY9yoqoN72w&list=PLoR9WSWWWLa1a75gqavwRoLviQs_V1u34&index=1&pp=gAQBiAQB). He is using Laravel but you can use the node/express app as the backend.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can check or modify this code. I'm using this code with Nuxt 2. For Nuxt 3, I think you need to modify it further. Create a new file(server.js) on the root directory and then update package.json with this.

```
"dev": "node index.js",
```

**server.js**

```
const { loadNuxt, build } = require("nuxt");
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());

async function start() {
  const nuxt = await loadNuxt(isDev ? "dev" : "start");
  app.use(nuxt.render);

  if (isDev) {
    await build(nuxt);
  }

  app.listen(port);
}

start();
```

Answer (score -1):

it would be possible using a legacy handler or middleware, but is not recommended...

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#legacy-handler-or-middleware